# OpenGL Image not loading correctly?

Tags: java, image, opengl, background, lwjgl

My Image is 1280x740 aswell as my game Canvas.

here is my code

```
// Initialize code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // end initializiation


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    getResources().backgroundImage.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); // Upper left
        glVertex2f(1280,0);

        glTexCoord2f(1,0); // Upper Right
        glVertex2f(0,0);

        glTexCoord2f(1,1); // Bottom Right
        glVertex2f(0,740);

        glTexCoord2f(0,1); // Bottom Left
        glVertex2f(1280,740);
    glEnd();
```

Here is the problem I'm getting, while trying to make this a full-screen texture... the image is actually being scaled down?

Image showing

http://i48.tinypic.com/inrbeu.png

Comment: From your image, it appears you may be rendering in _normalized device coordinates_, which is OpenGL's default coordinate system.  They range from [-1,1] in both X and Y coordinate directions.  The question is if you've specified a _projection transformation_.  Does your code contain a `gluOrtho2D`, or a `glOrtho` call (or less likely since you not explicitly specifying 3D coordinates, perhaps `gluPerspective` or `glFrustum` call)

Comment: No, this is going to be a strictly 2d program for now, I'm just trying to learn OpenGL...

inline `// Initialize code OpenGL glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // end initializiation'

Comment: 'code'// Initialize code OpenGL glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // end initializiation''code'  

This? Sorry, Like I said I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex position is transformed to viewport coordinates by either fixed function pipeline or a vertex shader. Without specifying those, the outcome is probably not what you want.

You need to either setup a projection·modelview or a shader matching your needs.

Comment: // Initialize code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // end initializiation


Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: `// Initialize code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // end initializiation`


Is this what you're talking about?

Sorry, just learned the Backtick thing

Comment: @ChristianTucker: Yes I meant this, and sorry, for some reason I didn't notice this at first in your code (probably because reading it on a small screen, then). Note that OpenGL is not really initialized, you should set those whenever you need it; with shader based OpenGL this happens as a neccessity, but in fixed function you can be lured into being lazy. Anyway, your code lacks proper setting of the modelview matrix. Either set it to identity (probably what you want) or something else. In your case it doesn't matter, but for projection setup it makes sense to choose `near < far`.